# Dropping points based on class number in lidR

Tags: lidr

I have a TLS point cloud which were classified into ground (class 2) and unclassified (class 1).

```
lasinfo (190812) report for 'infile.laz'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            0
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          'LAStools (c) by rapidlasso GmbH'
  generating software:        'las2las (version 190623)'
  file creation day/year:     50/2019
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       337
  number var. length records: 1
  point data format:          3
  point data record length:   34
  number of point records:    52463936
  number of points by return: 52463936 0 0 0 0
  scale factor x y z:         0.00025 0.00025 0.00025
  offset x y z:               695760.719696044921875 6106543.521759033203125 0
  min x y z:                  695760.73345 6106543.76051 -0.03700
  max x y z:                  695938.96420 6106715.68576 14.72325
variable length header record 1 of 1:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  56
  description          'GeoKeyDirectoryTag (mandatory)'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 6
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 2 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsPoint
      key 2052 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - GeogLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 2060 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAzimuthUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
      key 4099 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - VerticalUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
LASzip compression (version 3.4r1 c2 50000): POINT10 2 GPSTIME11 2 RGB12 2
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X                  55     712978
  Y                 955     688656
  Z                -148      58893
  intensity           0      65432
  return_number       1          1
  number_of_returns   1          1
  edge_of_flight_line 0          0
  scan_direction_flag 0          0
  classification      1          2
  scan_angle_rank     0          0
  user_data           0          0
  point_source_ID    64         64
  gps_time 194.000000 21782810.000000
WARNING: range violates GPS week time specified by global encoding bit 0
  Color R 0 61696
        G 0 59904
        B 0 64256
number of first returns:        52463936
number of intermediate returns: 0
number of last returns:         52463936
number of single returns:       52463936
overview over number of returns of given pulse: 52463936 0 0 0 0 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
        34352771  unclassified (1)
        18111165  ground (2)
```

I want to drop ground class 2 and keep class 1 in analysis:

```
> las_sf = readLAS("infile.laz", select = "xyzc", filter = "-keep_first -drop_z_below 0 ")
```

However, it doesn't seem to work:

```
> npoints(las_sf)
[1] 52463535
```

I am using lidR_3.0.1

How can I work around this?

Comment: I can see you have LASTools, try LAS2LAS -keep_class 1 see http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2las_README.txt and find (Ctrl + F) the line *Filter points based on classifications or flags*, this can be used to extract the class 1 from a whole folder of LAS or LAZ (or even txt) into a new, empty, folder as LAS, LAZ (or even TXT).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson. I don't have lastools license unfortunately. Therefore, I am trying to use lidR. lasinfo is available for free, that's why I used it.

Comment: LAS2LAS may also be one of the free tools, or it may be limited to 50k points or not LAZ. Try it and see if it works; if you are going to work with LiDAR data a lot please consider purchasing a license. The options for lidR https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/readLAS.html in the example show *very* similar options to LASTools, try changing your filter = "-keep_class 1" and see if that does what you want, your current filter will return all points above 0 elevation as they're all flagged as first (see your number of returns in LASInfo).

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelStimson. filter = "-keep_class 1" worked. Surprisingly, keep_class is not given in lidR document. I thought "-keep_first" means to keep class not return.

Comment: Excellent, now please answer your own question, as this is undocumented your answer will be invaluable to future users of lidR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lidR` uses `rlas` to read LAS/LAZ files. `rlas` is a wrapper of `LASlib` and `LASzip` in R meaning that all the filters in `LAStools` are also in `lidR`

You can use `filter = "-drop_class 2"`

Check the documentation of `readLAS` to find all the filters with :

```
readLAS(filter = "-help")
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of Michael Stimson, `"filter ("-keep_class 1")"` kept only class 1 points and dropped the class 2. I also tested the functionality of some filters in LAS2LAS if they work in lidR and functions such as `drop_z`, `-last_only` also worked which is great, however not listed in lidR documentation.  It would be great to see `lidR keep class`, `lidR drop z`, `lidR last only` filters in future versions of lidR documentation.

Comment: If you have some free time perhaps try some of the other filters mentioned in LAS2LAS and see if they work also, edit the functional/dysfunctional query switches into your answer. If the lidR documentation is a bit sketchy a canonical list of filters that work would be useful and you may even end up with *popular question* notoriety. Answers are searchable so anyone that Googles *"lidR keep class"* will lead them here.

Comment: Thanks Michael Stimpson, I tested some other filters from LAS2LAS and they worked which is amazing. I added them to the response.

Comment: All the filters are accessible in lidR.  Check out the documentation ;-)